# Why MonadReader r (StateT s m) uses an instance of the underlying monad

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

As far as I can see, we could implement `MonadReader s (StateT s m)` instance:

```
instance MonadReader s (StateT s m) where
    ask = get
    local f m = do
        s <- get
        put (f s)
        m
        put s
```

i.e. why it isn't

```
class MonadReader s m => MonadState s m | s -> m where ...
```

Similarly we could have `Monoid s => MonadWriter s (StateT s m)` instance.

Is there some deep reason between the choice?

---

This question is motivated by whether `MonadError` and `MonadWriter` should be
super classes of [`MonadChronicle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.2/docs/Control-Monad-Chronicle.html#t:MonadChronicle)

Comment: It's just limitation of mtl. You can see other libraries. [This post](https://ro-che.info/articles/extensible-effects) can help you more.

Comment: @freestyle, that post is about slightly different problem. I tried to clarify the question: why MonadReader isn't a superclass of MonadState

Comment: I think you would want to ask another question: Why I can't use MonadReader or MonadWriter interface when I have the State monad on my stack? So I've just tried to answer on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could do that, but it would violate the spirit of `mtl` and potentially lead to API issues. The idea of `mtl` is that each standard monad transformer adds one or more distinct effects. Adding `StateT` and `ReaderT` to the transformer stack give you a state and an environment. If `StateT` implemented its own `MonadReader` instance, then you'd have access to just the state blob, through two different interfaces. To add an environment to the mix, you'd have to work with the transformers "manually". If you see `MonadChronicle` as offering effects you might want to layer on top of writer and exception effects, then you should keep them separate. If you see it as an extension/refinement of those effects, then superclasses make sense.

Comment: So, I could write `RWST s m` (n.b: only `s`), implementing `MonadReader s`, `MonadWriter s` and `MonadState s`. I wonder is anyone has made such in their public or private developments. I suspect that with lenses, only one transformer would be enough. 

I'm keen to learn about potential API issues.

Comment: @phadej I would call that `State2` or something else, but not `RWS`, since the point of `RWS` is having a guaranteed read-only part and a guaranteed append-only part, beyond the read/write part of the state. If there is only `s`, I guess we actually have a `State` newtype except with more instances (which is not a bad idea, for the reasons you mention).

Answer (score 0):

I think, aside from the nice theoretical/philosophical reasons about the `MonadReader` instance for `StateT`, I think that the current set-up is also the most *practical*.

It's more *useful* to have `MonadReader` and `MonadState` give different functionality.  Then you can leverage `ask` and `get` to do two different things.  If `ask` and `get` did the same thing, it'd pretty much be redundant functionality.  Having them do separate things is much more practical and gives you much more flexibility in the usage of `StateT` through its `MonadReader` and `MonadState` instances/interfaces.

It's a similar reason to why `mappend` and `<|>` for `Maybe` do different things.  It'd just be a waste of potential utility :)

I'd imagine that if `StateT` gave the same behavior for `ask` and `get`, people would be complaining about how impractical/limiting it'd be.

Comment: The fact that `mappend` and `<|>` for `Maybe` do different things is most unfortunate.

Comment: @dfeuer Why do you think it's unfortunate? There's an [`Alt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Alt) wrapper for that, as well as [`First`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First).